# Java Generics w <extends> ... why does this code compile?

Tags: java, generics

I've never known how `extends` and `super` work with Java Generics, so I've been playing around a bit. I've gotten something I don't understand. I'll let the code do the talking ...

```
public class Tests 
{
    // Some straightforward sample tyes
    class Vehicle {}
    class Car extends Vehicle {}
    
    // Generic list factory method for Vehicles and all subtypes
    private static <T extends Vehicle> List<T> createVehicleList ()
    {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }


    @Test
    public void funWithExtends ()
    {
        // This works because the type is explicitly specified
        List<Car> alsoCars = Tests.<Car>createVehicleList();

        // This works because of type inference ... I think
        List<Car> cars = createVehicleList();

        // Here's where it gets weird. Why is this legal?
        Object weirdCars = createVehicleList();
        List<?> list = (List<?>)weirdCars;
        list.add(null);
        // This next line doesn't compile - I can't add() anything but null
        //   list.add(new Vehicle());
        Object el = list.get(0);
        System.out.println(String.format("el = %s", el));
        assertEquals(null, el);
    }
}
```

In my last call to `createVehicleList()`, I do not give the compiler any clue as to what type of List I want. I expected a compiler error. Instead, the function executes just fine, and returns a strange list. The list is apparently valid, but I cannot add anything to the list except `null`, presumably because `null` has no type, at least for these purposes.

Is there a fundamental, conceptual reason for this that I'm missing? Or is it just a strange corner case, in a 30+ year old language that is adding modern features, while supporting syntactic sugar to reduce pain (eg type inference), while also focusing on backward compatability. Thanks!

Comment: Presumably, `Object weirdCars = createVehicleList();` is "inferring" `List<Vechicle>`, as that's the upper bound of `T`, and all reference types are an `Object`, so the assignment works.

Comment: Also, you can't use `add` on a `List<?>` because `?` means that you don't know what is allowed in it. For instance, a `List<String>` would be a `List<?>` but doesn't allow adding a `LocalDate`.

Comment: Gilad Bracha’s excellent [explanation of Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/), now part of the official Java tutorial, taught me everything about how Java generics work.  It is invaluable.

Comment: @Slaw I've confirmed this is correct. I'm able to cast `weirdCars` above to a `List<Vehicle>`, and then I can assign a new `Vehicle`, `Car`, or `Boat`. Etc. This must have been the one thing I didn't try. Thanks!

Comment: You'll be able to cast `weirdCars` to any `List` parameterization; even, for example, `List<String>`. There's a reason this is an unchecked cast.

Comment: @Slaw Agreed, I meant I could cast and then use it as expected. Simply surviving a cast is indeed a low bar.

Comment: @VGR Thanks! That was a very good read. I definitely didn't understand it all the first time through, but it helped a few things, and it's good to know it's there for rereads. Interesting one of the people named in the Acknowledgements is Mads Torgersen, of C# fame.

Comment: I don’t understand your question. You can write `List<?> listOfUnknown=createVehicleList(); Object weirdCars = listOfUnknown;` so why should the compiler not allow to write `Object weirdCars = createVehicleList();` which does the same without the intermediate variable? As a side note, it’s weird to write `System.out.println(String.format("el = %s", el));` If you like the formatting API, just use `System.out.printf("el = %s%n", el);` to format and print. If you like simplicity and efficiency, just write `System.out.println("el = " + el);`

Comment: @Holger I didn't know about `System.out.printf()` -- now that I know about it, I may never explicitly call `String.format()` again. Thanks!

Comment: `String.format` has its place; whenever the string is the result you want. What’s funny about it, is that `printf` usually is the known thing, as it is also the name of a much older C function and the percent placeholder syntax often called “printf syntax” and `String.format` often described as “when you want to printf into a string”.

Answer (score 3):

```
Object weirdCars = createVehicleList();
```

The `creeateVehicleList()` invokes the `createVehicleList` method, which declares a fresh new type variable. That's the `T` surrounded by exclamation points in `private static <!!T!! extends Vehicle> List<T> createVehicleList ()` - the second usage of T (`List<T>`) is not declaring a new type var, no, that's *using it*.

A type var is best understood as follows:

The **user**, i .e. the caller, of `createVehicleList` is forced to pick some type T. This T is restricted here; the caller gets to pick any type it wants, but, that type must either be Vehicle, or any subtype of it. So, a caller can pick Vehicle, or it can pick Car, or it can pick Bike, or it can pick Airplane, or it can pick Froobargle. Froobargles don't exist yet. Nobody knows what they are. In 2049, someone will invent a vehicle called Froobargle. You can't plan for this. But it will be a vehicle by then.

Hence, your method declaration is now constrained by the compiler: Given that you write only one method declaration, but there are a potentially infinite number of *users* of that declaration (callers), and each caller gets to pick a vehicle type to bind to their particular 'take' on T, and it is in fact impossible to enumerate all choices, given that in 2049 someone is going to invent a Floobargle which is a kind of vehicle, the code of `createVehicleListz` must deal with the fact that __T is a meta-type': It stands for every possible vehicle, all at once. In other words, your code must be valid **for *all* possible choices**. Your code must make sense if T is Bike. It must make sense if T is Car. It must make sense if T is Vehicle. It must make sense if T is Feoobargle.

Hence, 2 constraints are created here:

- A call to `createVehicleList()` **must** either [A] explicitly make clear what type you want, i.e. `Foo.<Car>createVehicleList()`, or [B] needs to implicitly make that clear, e.g. `Foo<Car> f = Foo.createVehicleList()` (the compiler infers what type you want here from context), or [C] you get a warning that the compiler can't follow along (generics are gone once compiled; it's purely a figment of the compiler's imagination, it's compiler-documentation type documentation), or [D] the compiler must be able to ascertain it doesn't matter.
- The code within the `createVehicleList` must make sense for **all possible choices**, even the ones we can't enumerate yet, such as the Froobargle choice which isn't going to be sensible until 2049 when that is invented.

Hence:

`Object x = createVehicleList()` is fine, because that's a D case: It doesn't matter. for compilation purposes the compiler picks the lower bound (Vehicle) here, which then ceases to be relevant. Generics exist solely as compiler-checked documentation, and you've opted to ignore any and all bounds here, `x` has no types associated with it, so, the compiler can just recognize it has nothing to do and completely ignore it.

---

```
List<?> list = (List<?>)weirdCars;
```

This is fine, of course. You're casting an expression of type `Object` to `List` which is valid java: Java will inject some bytecode which has only 2 options: Either [A] that expression resolves to a value that is indeed an instance of `List`, or `null`, in which case this **does absolutely nothing at all**, or [B] it isn't, in which case __this is a weird way to write `throw new ClassCastException()`. This kind of cast *does not ever* convert anything. It merely does either nothing at all, or throws. Lists need a type param and as type params are a figment of the compiler's imagination and casting is a runtime thing, there's nothing left to say, but, fortunately, that ? works out: ? means, literally: **don't know**. `Lis<?>` does not mean: "This is a list that can hold whatever". It means: "This is a list that contains **I do not know**. There *is* a constraint. I just do not know what it is. It might be a list constrained to contain only strings. It might be a list constraint to contain only sets of maps of strings to integers. It might be a list that can contain everything (effectively, `Object` - all things are objects). I just don't know".

That's the only fair cast you can make here. You have no idea what the constraint might be and `?` accurately represents 'no idea - ensure whatever code I write is valid regardless of what constraint exists'.

---

```
list.add(null);
```

The `list` expression is of type `List<?>` which, as we covered, means: "A list which is constrained to only contain things of some type and unfortunately I have no idea what that is".

The compiler will ensure that any code you wrote works for **all possible valid choices within that domain**. So, that constraint could be 'strings', 'integers', 'doubles', 'inputstreams', or 'lists of sets of maps of strings to lists of froobargles' - we just do not know. So, what thing can you pass to the `add` method that works **for ALL of those choices**?

The one, and only, value, is `null`. It's not because `null` has no type. Quite the opposite. `null`, the literal, is *every* type. And only an expression that is all types at once could possibly fit when the code needs to work for all cases, whether that ? is Integer, String, or `Set<Map<String, List<Froobargle>>`.

Hence, yeah, a `List<?>` or `List<? extends Whatever>` **cannot** be added to, except the academic (i.e. useless) case of the null literal.

That's the point.

### An important case to think about

In java, the basic type system is **covariant**. Meaning, any expression of some type is valid anytime an expression of some supertype is needed. Stated simply, this:

```
Number n = new Integer(5);
```

is legal java.

However, generics **just do not play that game** - generics are **invariant**. If `Number` is needed, only `Number` will do. We can see this too:

```
List<Number> n = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

does not compile.  The problem isn't the ArrayList part - basic java says that any subtype is a valid standin and ArrayList is a subtype of List. No, the problem is the generics: shoving `<Integer>` is no good, it must be `<Number>` and nothing else will do. The reason is because **that's just how math / the universe is**.

Imagine we doggedly ignore the universe and say that should work. Then I Can write this:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> numbers = ints; // hey, you wanted this to be legal.
Number z = new Double(5.5); // this HAS to be legal.
numbers.add(z); // so does this; of course I can add a number to a list of numbers.
Integer i = ints.get(0); // this has to be legal too
```

Every step other than the second line is obviously correct, and yet, we end up trying to shove a double value into a variable of type Integer which obviously cannot be allowed. The answer to this paradox is that the second line is lying: `List<Number> n = someListOfInt;` does **not** compile at all, because it **cannot** - if that was allowed you run into this clusterbomb of a situation.

Hence, generics are **invariant**.

However, this raises an issue: What if you write a method that never adds anything to a list (which it got as an argument); it only reads from that list. This method demands that the values in said list are numbers, but the method can deal with `List<Number>`, `List<Integer>`, `List<Double>` - any number you like, as long as its a list of some sort of type that is Number or a subtype of it. In plain java you can write a method `void foo(Number n)` and rest assured that a caller can pass a double, an integer, or anything else that is a subtype of Number. But generics bounds have to be covariant, so a method `void foo(List<Number> n)` cannot be invoked with a `List<Integer>` argument, because if you could, that `foo` method could add a double to your list of integers and we don't want that.

So, we want methods to be able to handcuff themselves: A tradeoff; I shall promise not to add anything to the list, but I do want the ability to assume that any object in this list is null or an instance of Vehicle or some subtype thereof. In trade for these handcuffs, the compiler will take a chill pill and allow callers to pass `List<Vehicle>`, `List<Car>`, `List<Bike>`, and even, come 2049, `List<Froobargle>`.

And, yay, you can do that. `List<? extends Vehicle>` is what you want. You can't add anything to this list, because no x in `list.add(x)` will work for ALL possible cases (those cases being `List<Vehicle>`, `List<Car>`, `List<Bike>`, and `List<Froobargle>` - there can be an infinite number of imaginable vehicles, hence, the actual use cases are infinite). Well, except literally `list.add(null)`, of course.

`? extends Vehicle` is opting back into covariance. Which adds handcuffs: The compiler will ensure you don't break stuff. Which you will, if you call `.add`, so the compiler will ensure you don't call that.